# exc_bad_instruction when setting UIView center to cgpoint

Tags: swift, exc-bad-instruction

I've just started learning Swift, and I've been trying to move a UIView in response to a touch. I'm getting an `exc_bad_instruction` error.

```
var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y:0)
@IBOutlet weak var person: UIView!

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch : UITouch! = touches.first

    location = touch.location(in: self.view)

    person.center = location
}
```

Comment: which line is throwing error?

Comment: @Mr.UB The 6th line

Comment: what is the type of `center` and also what is the output of `print(location)`?

Comment: @Mr.UB center is a cgpoint as seen here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622627-center

Comment: @Mr.UB the print(location) prints the coordinate location of the point I last clicked. For example: (146.0, 169.0)

Comment: declared like `var center:CGPoint`? and `Person` is an `Object` or `Class` name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exc_bad_instruction` usually is a hint for a null pointer. Make sure `Person` is not nil.

Also make sure to name your properties to have a lower case letter at the beginning - in this case this would be `person`. When using `Person` you run the risk to call the Type not the Propery.

If you need further help, please edit your post and add further code samples of your project - specifically of the Class `Person` and the whole `UIViewController` where you use it.

Answer (score 0):

The variable location should have been declared as explicitly a CGPoint:

```
var location : CGPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
```